# How to count the elements of an array inside an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a method which returns the number of hotels from a webpage:

```
hotel_count = self.getHotelsList.values
```

The output of this method is:

```
[["hotel_0", "hotel_1", "hotel_2", "hotel_3", "hotel_4", "hotel_5", "hotel_6", "hotel_7", "hotel_8", "hotel_9", "hotel_10", "hotel_11", "hotel_12", "hotel_13", "hotel_14", "hotel_15", "hotel_16", "hotel_17", "hotel_18", "hotel_19", "hotel_20", "hotel_21", "hotel_22", "hotel_23", "hotel_24", "hotel_25", "hotel_26", "hotel_27", "hotel_28", "hotel_29", "hotel_30", "hotel_31", "hotel_32", "hotel_33", "hotel_34", "hotel_35", "hotel_36", "hotel_37", "hotel_38", "hotel_39", "hotel_40"]]
```

I want to know the length of this array, but if I write

```
hotel_count = self.getHotelsList.values.length
```

The length is 1. How can I get a length of 41, which is the one I'm expecting?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array you are showing is nested inside another array. So the outer array *is* of length 1, the inner array is what you want.

To get it you have to first get the first element of the outer array using `[0]` or `first`

```
testList[0].length
testList.first.length
```

I am not sure why your `getHotelsList` method returns a nested array, it doesn't appear to need it.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying with [0] but couldn't make it work. Using 'first' did the trick, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
hotel_count = getHotelsList.values.first.length
```

You can also do it with `[0]`, but `first` is faster.

Two notes:

- You don't need `self` at the beginning.
- It is a bad habit to use camel case for method names in Ruby. it should better be `get_hotels_list`.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert that into a single array with `flatten`:

```
hotel_count = self.getHotelsList.values.flatten.size
```